# trigger JS func programmatically from url

Tags: javascript, c#, html-agility-pack

I need to pull html content from website with table and parse it. Problem is that table is not showing all items on initial load, but you have button Show All.
Is there a way to trigger that button (function) from code and then retrieve the html content?

Comment: Not if you are making the request from a server. Nope.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with selenium.
Open url in browser, click on button, retrieve data from table.